# Is there any Microsoft Graph API endpoint that would allow us to add a desired app to a teams meeting?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I have a teams meeting extension app which I want to programmatically add to a meeting. At the moment, I have only been able to manually add an app to a meeting before, during and after a meeting(through Outlook/MS Teams) but I want to be able to do it from my code calling API. Is there any API endpoint provided by Microsoft which would allow us to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can Install a [teamsApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamsapp?view=graph-rest-1.0) to the specified [chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chat?view=graph-rest-1.0). If the chat is associated with an [onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0) instance, then, effectively, the teamsApp will get installed to the meeting.

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var requestBody = new TeamsAppInstallation
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {
            "teamsApp@odata.bind" , "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/12345678-9abc-def0-123456789a"
        },
    },
};
var result = await graphClient.Chats["{chat-id}"].InstalledApps.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Reference Document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#examples

Comment: when I create a teams meeting, shouldn't a chat be automatically created for it?
I tried calling the api endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats to access all my chats but I noticed that it gave me the list of only the chats which has some message in it.
So, the question is, when we create a teams meeting, does a teams chat get automatically created? If so, why didn't https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/chats return a chat id for the new teams meeting that I created?
And if a chat meeting is actually created when I create a new teams meeting, how do I access it?

Comment: when you create a Microsoft Teams meeting, a corresponding chat is not automatically created. However, you can easily start a chat related to the meeting manually.